# Installation Problem Magento 2.3.5p1 on Centos 7

Tags: magento2.3, nginx, centos, mariadb

I have been trying to install Magento on Centos 7 with Nginx and Maria Db for the past 2-3 days now but each time I got errors. I have tried several ways and changed Nginx configuration file and tried many possible solutions available on stackoverflow and Magento docs.

I was only able to install it correctly once, but that was giving me server level error i.e. `php-fpm security.limit_extensions`. Therefore, I made the necessary changes to Nginx and I am not getting this error anymore. However, now my installation has 404 error on all the CSS and other files. As shown in the image below.

Store Home Page:

[image]

Store Admin Panel
[image]

Nginx logs are full of errors like:

```
> 2020/07/05 08:23:45 [error] 8864#8864: *94 open()
> "/var/www/user/pub/static/version1593936946/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css"
> failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server:
> www.domain.com, request: "GET
> /pub/static/version1593936946/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css
> HTTP/1.1", host: "www.user.com", referrer:
> "https://www.user.com/index.php/admin_h7r4ak/admin/index/index/key/57fe0e9d24ad111c0afbf63b34a7fd456106047e74662ae8a/"
```

I have tried to give magento directory permissions with both, `files and & dir as 777' and also as mentioned in Magento docs i.e.

> find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec
> chmod g+w {} + find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc
> -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +

But this does not help. I have tried to install with both users i.e. `nginx:nginx` and user that i added to nginx group `user:nginx`. The result is same, as shown in the above images.

My Nginx.conf file:

> ```
>     server {
>     listen   80;
>     server_name  example.com;
>     root /var/www/example;
>     return   301 https://www.example.com$request_uri; 
>     }
>     server {
>     listen   80;
>     server_name  www.example.com;
>     root /var/www/example;
>     return   301 https://www.example.com$request_uri; 
>     } 
>     server {
>     listen   443 ssl http2;
>     server_name example.com;
>     keepalive_timeout    70;
>     root   /var/www/example;
>     return   301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
>
>     gzip    on;
>     ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
>     ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
>     ssl_protocols   TLSv1.2;
>     ssl_ciphers     EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!3DES;
>     ssl_dhparam     /etc/nginx/conf.d/dhparam.pem;
>     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
>     ssl_session_tickets     off;
>     ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m; 
>     }
>
>     server {
>     listen   443 ssl http2;
>     server_name www.example.com;
>     keepalive_timeout    70;
>
>     gzip    on;
>     #       modsecurity on;
>     #       modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;
>
>     ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
>     ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
>     ssl_protocols   TLSv1.2;
>     ssl_ciphers     EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!3DES;
>     ssl_dhparam     /etc/nginx/conf.d/dhparam.pem;
>     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
>     ssl_session_tickets     off;
>     ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
>
>     add_header   X-Frame-Options "DENY";
>     add_header   X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
>
>     access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
>     error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;
>
>
>     set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/example;      root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
>           charset UTF-8;      autoindex off;
>   
>     location / {
>             root   /var/www/example;
>             #try_files $uri $uri/ = /404.html;
>             if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
>             try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
>             #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
>             index  index.php index.html;
>             add_header   Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains" always;
>     }
>
>     error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
>     # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
>     #
>     error_page  500 502 503 504  = /errors/50x.php;
>
>   # PHP entry point for update application        
>   location ~* ^/update($|/) {
>       root $MAGE_ROOT;
>       index  index.php;
>       location ~ ^/update/index.php {
>           fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
>           fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;
>           fastcgi_index  index.php;
>           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
>           fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
>           include        fastcgi_params;
>       }
>
>       # Deny everything but index.php
>       location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
>           deny all;
>       }
>
>       location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
>           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
>       }       }
>
>
>   location /pub/ {
>   location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml)
>   {
>           deny all;
>       }
>       alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
>       add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";        }
>
>   location /static/ {
>       # Uncomment the following line in production mode
>       # expires max;
>
>       # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
>       location ~ ^/static/version {
>           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
>       }
>
>       location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json)$
>       {
>           add_header Cache-Control "public";
>           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
>           expires +1y;
>
>           if (!-f $request_filename) {
>               rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
>           }
>       }
>
>       location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
>           add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
>           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
>           expires    off;
>
>           if (!-f $request_filename) {
>                   rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
>           }
>       }
>           if (!-f $request_filename) {
>           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
>       }
>       add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";        }
>
>   location /media/ {
>       try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
>
>       location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
>           deny all;
>       }
>
>       location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
>           add_header Cache-Control "public";
>           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
>           expires +1y;
>           try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
>       }
>       location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
>           add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
>           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
>           expires    off;
>           try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
>       }
>       add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";        }
>
>   location /media/customer/ { deny all; }
>
>   location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
>
>   location /media/import/ { deny all; }
>
>   location /media/custom_options/ { deny all; }
>
>   location /errors/ {
>       location ~* \.xml$ { deny all; }        }
>
>   # Deny access to sensitive files        
>   location /.user.ini { deny all; }
>
>   ######################################################################
>   ######################################################################
>
>     # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
>     #
>     location ~* \.php$ {
>             root           /var/www/example;
>             fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
>             fastcgi_index  index.php;
>             fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
>             if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {  return 302 /$1?$args;  }
>             try_files $uri = 404;
>             fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
>             fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING  $query_string;
>             fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
>             fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE  $content_type;
>             fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;
>             fastcgi_intercept_errors  on;
>             
>             fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
>             fastcgi_connect_timeout  600s;
>             fastcgi_read_timeout  600s;
>             fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;
>             include  fastcgi_params;
>     }
>
>
>   gzip_disable "msie6";       
>   gzip_comp_level 6;      
>   gzip_min_length 1100;
>   gzip_buffers 16 8k;
>   gzip_proxied any;
>   gzip_types
>       text/plain
>       text/css
>       text/js
>       text/xml
>       text/javascript
>       application/javascript
>       application/x-javascript
>       application/json
>       application/xml
>       application/xml+rss
>       image/svg+xml;      gzip_vary on;
>
>   # Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
>   location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
>       deny all;       }
>
>     # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
>     # concurs with nginx's one
>     #
>     location ~ /\.ht {
>             deny  all;
>     } 
>     }
> ```

I have set `memory_limit` to `3G` and execution timeout to `18000`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In development mode (the default after installing magento2) the app deploys assets to pub/static and also uses var/view_preprocessed to generate files. Try rm -rf pub/static/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*

Personally, i make a user called magento and add it to the www-data group, with a php-fpm pool configured for that user. I then sudo su - magento (for user magento) and deploy in there, saves problems with permissions every deployment. Happy to help if have issues still, for now though, add your user to www-data, then chown -r user:www-data the entire magento dir, and clear the static and view_preprocessed dirs

Comment: i have tried this way, ssh'd into the magento user which was in `nginx` group.  installed magento successfully and finally executed this command `rm -rf pub/static/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*`. However, its same black messed up home and admin panel.

Comment: The errors you show indicate either a. The folder can't be written to, or b. Incorrect nginx configuration. Is the folder being written to? E.g are you seeing content in there after flush cache and reload? (bin/magento c:f)

Comment: this is the output >> `bin/magento c:f
Flushed cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
reflection
db_ddl
compiled_config
eav
customer_notification
config_integration
config_integration_api
google_product
full_page
config_webservice
translate
vertex`

I have also given my nginx config file in the Question. I am not sure if something is wrong with that. Can you review?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: here is the result >> [link](https://imgur.com/X4udmiM) . you can see the content of `pub/static` directory too. However, the website searches for CSS files in `pub/static/version1593957476/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css' `. I do not see any version* folder

Comment: Ah I see. You will NOT see a "version*" folder. This is normal. Try flushing your cache and see if your assets are loading on the frontend now.

Comment: `bin/magento c:f` I see same result. in the `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/` directory I can find the file `style-l.css`, however it gives 404 error in the web URL `https://www.domain.com/pub/static/version1593959619/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css`

Comment: I executed this command, but nothing... same missing files. `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Double check your nginx configuration. If everything seems ok and you still can't get the version location to resolve, you can try disabling static file signing. Run this command at the cli then redeploy: `bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 0`

Comment: 1) tried c:c, c:f, did not work 
2) di:compile, upgrade followed by deploy... did not work. 
3) disabled magento_csp... did not work
I can login to admin panel, can see dashboard, however then there is a loader and I am stuck here with it.
I changed mode to developer, and flushed cache. still same.
I noticed... Although I have added my user to nginx group, but the new directories and files generated/created by MAGENTO, are by nginx:nginx instead of my user:nginx,
can this be a reason? that i am facing this issue. but then how to fix it?

Comment: @nix they're getting created by nginx because your php-fpm user (declared in the pool conf) will be seeing that. Check out the https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-magento-2-on-ubuntu-18-04/ 'magento.conf' section. In dev mode, assets are created on page load by the webserver

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews I just created a pool successfully, and then did a fresh installation. now the new files/directories are being created as user:nginx instead of nginx:nginx, which i think is good. However, its same on admin panel, loader keeps showing : (

Comment: Progress! The admin panel loading is to do with assets not being generated most likely, have you tried adding your user to the nginx group? although the files should be getting generated by user:www-data - what's the parent directory owned by? as /var/www/html is owned by nginx as default

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews I think its mostly because of requirejs* file, coz apart from other files in logs browser js log, i see this file the most. Of course I have added user to nginx group and created the pool, and yes now files/dir's are being created as user:nginx. Parent directory `/var/www/user` is owned by `user:nginx`.

Comment: parent directory needs to be owned by user:www-data if the php pool is user:www-data, otherwise magento won't be able to write to it

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews Yes parent directory is owned by `user:nginx`, I already mentioned it above. Can i move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110267/discussion-between-ricky-odin-matthews-and-nix).

Answer (score 0):

go to your magento root directory navigate to `app/etc/di.xml`

search for `symlink` and replace it with `Copy`
now just `flush:cache` and check

Comment: I have already tried this, but the admin panel keeps loading, and javascript log shows some files missing. as shown in the image [link](https://i.imgur.com/EWGTf6c.png)

Comment: i think you need to set perimission for pub/static just give it a try

Comment: i have tried sooooo many ways, i gave all kinds of permission, 777/755/077/g+w/g+ws etc to files and directories. But each time, its same. I am using only SSL, i have HTTP disabled on server. I am not sure if it has to do something with it. Although, home page works fine.

Comment: switch to developer mode and then run the deploy command or clear everything from pub static and generated

Comment: I am already using developer mode and not default or production. I have also tried `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` several times now.

@Chikku I don't have `generated` directory in `pub/static` , is it normal?

Comment: run php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110260/discussion-between-nix-and-chikku).